# NextJS - api submit form data

Tags: node.js, next.js

So not sure why but I am trying to submit my form data to `/api/new`

But when I do I get the following error

```
./pages/api/new.js
Error: 
  x Expected '(', got 'new'
   ,----
 2 | export default function new(req, res) {
   :                         ^^^
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to process input file
    1: Syntax Error
```

Not sure why but seems to only be an issue when I have inputs that are file type.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a reserved keyword and you cannot use reserved keywords as function, variable, label, or class names. Try naming the handler `newRouteHandler` or something else.